# bindParam не работает на ALTER TABLE X ADD :XXX

Tags: php, pdo

**bindParam** работает со значениями, но не работает с именами, как это исправить?

```
$cache = XXXX->prepare('ALTER TABLE XXX ADD :name varchar(2) NOT NULL;');
$cache->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$cache->execute();
```

Comment: И не будет работать. SQL не предусматривает возможность передавать элементы DDL предложений (в т.ч. alter table) как параметры. подставляйте значение непосредственно в текст

Comment: Ага из самой $name, инъекцию хотите?

Comment: А иначе ни как при вашей постановке задачи. имена полей не могут содержать кавычек и точек с запятой, так что просто удалите их из строки и инъекция исключена.

Comment: И кстати, обратите внимание, что добавить NOT NULL колонку к таблице, в которой уже есть записи, физически не возможно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Азбука баз данных:

Структура БД меняется только при обновлении сайта, и никогда - на лету.

Если вдруг требуется добавлять поля в таблицу из пользовательского ввода - это значит, что **БД спроектирована неверно**

Comment: Это не ответ. Пример есть таблица в ней есть строчки(пользователи) и есть столбцы(кукуруза, помидоры) требуется добавить товар на пользователя(картошка) и в последующем это поле будет либо +1 либо -1(количество купленного товара). Создавать таблицу еще одну чтобы хранить в ней id и значение кортошки? а если там будет товаров за тыщю, что будет с самим mysql которому проще работать с одной строкой, чем искать сотню с именем товара картошка и его количества.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров я пожалуй соглашусь с Иптьевым "**БД спроектирована неверно**". Добавлять на каждый торвар колонку - так в реляционных базах не делают. Делают справочник видов товара, где картошке назначен id и делается таблица вида "пользователь, вид товара, количество"

Comment: А вот вопрос, если требуется получить товаров штук 20? Предложите создать mysql запросов штук 20? Мне кажется проще получить 1 строчку содержащюю все что мне требуется а?

Comment: @ДенисКотляров Получить одну строчку конечно проще. но и 20 запросов делать не надо, одним запросом получаете список. И вы сказали что у вас будет товаров за тысячу. 1000 колонок, даже если БД позволит - это катастрофа. Даже если они NULL, заголовок записи должен содержать 125 байт оглавления и что самое печальное добавление каждой восьмой колонки потребует удлинения всех записей, которое повлечет за собой массовый переезд записей в другие блоки, что повлечет капитальную деградацию ввода-вывода

Comment: @ДенисКотляров И создать индекс по которому вы сможете быстро найти например все записи в которых есть такой то товар будет невозможно, что приведет к перебору всей таблицы при любом поиске чего либо

Comment: Вот теперь я вижу ответ. Хорошо сделаю записи, получать буду по id и будет практически как одна строчка но немного по другому обрабатывать. Спасибо за совет.